# beta coefficient in Anova with R and XLStat

Tags: r, statistics, anova, beta

I’m working with the software `R` and `XLStat`. I’ve conducted an one-way `ANOVA` (my categorical variable is 3 modal (1,2,3) and my response variable is quantitative on scale 1-10).

I’ve conducted this ANOVA on R and XLStat and the outputs for the F fisher, p-value, coefficient estimations, t-values, std error … are exactly the same.

However, XLstat offers an extra output : the standardized coefficients (called too beta coefficients). Firstly, I was surprised, because I didn’t think we could calculate beta coefficient for a categorical variable and according to the bibliography I read, it doesn’t have any sense.

Anyway, I tried to find these coefficients with R, thanks to the unique formula I found : `beta = estimate * sd(x)/sd(y)`. sd(x) being the standard deviation of the categorical variable (which is automatically transformed as numeric variable with R, in order to calculate sd(x), seems logical  ) and sd(y) being the standard deviation of my response variable.

The first beta I obtained with R is the same than in XLstat , but not the second and the third. Given that the first one is the same with R and XLStat, I suppose that Xlstat convert too the categorical variable in numeric variable (which is senseless but this is not the question). 
Moreover, I conducted the anova on Statistica in order to see if XLStat did any mistake but its outputs for the beta coefficients are the same than in Xlstat …

So, my question is this one : what is the formula to obtain the beta coefficient in a one way Anova ?

Then, I would like to ask you about the relevance of these beta coefficients for a categorical variable. According to my thoughts and publications I read, it doesn't have any sense …

ps contrasts in R and Xlstat are sum(ai)=0. For beta coefficients, XLStat remove the intercept. I guess this fact could be important but I don't know somehow

Answer (score 1):

The formula for obtaining beta coefficients from metric coefficients for an ANOVA is the same as for a linear regression. The coefficients have no sensible interpretation (for categorical variables), but standardized coefficients are useful in comparing the relative effects of IVs with different metrics.

In R, either use scale() to transform the data to z-scores before fitting the model, or use lm.beta() instead of lm().

It is not clear why you would obtain different beta coefficients with XLStat, but it could have something to do with degrees of freedom if it's not an error. [This example](http://www.r-bloggers.com/example-8-14-generating-standardized-regression-coefficients/) compares the lm.beta() function in R with SAS and obtains the same coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

However, I tried lots of methods, including scaling my variable (response, categorical or both) and the function lm.beta too but I don't get the same beta coefficients than XLStat and Statistica ...

I suppose so Xlstat and Statistica used another formula than the one I wrote  in my previous message 'beta = estimate * sd(x)/sd(y)', maybe they include another term, given that we deal with categorical variable ? But I'm still suprised because the first beta I obtained with R with this formula or the lm.beta function is the same than the first in XLStat and Statistica ...

Comment: Moreover, I've already read this example which compares lm.beta function in R and SAS outputs. However, it concerns linear regression with quantitative IV and not categorical as they are in ANOVA.

Comment: ANOVA is linear regression with a dummy variable instead of a continuous variable, the coefficients are calculated exactly the same way. Do you have a reproducible worked example?